# How to create repetitive values column (using hours) for ID numbers for each date available?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**In the following example of a data frame:**

| Date | ID number |
| --- | --- |
| 15/06/2022 | 1523 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1402 |

**I'm trying to add a column in pandas to a the data frame that has repetitive values, such as:**

| Date | ID number | Hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15/06/2022 | 1523 | 1 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1523 | 2 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1523 | 4 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1523 | 5 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1523 | 6 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1523 | 7 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1523 | 8 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1402 | 1 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1402 | 2 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1402 | 4 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1402 | 5 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1402 | 6 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1402 | 7 |
| 15/06/2022 | 1402 | 8 |

**How is this possible please? Thanks in advance**

Comment: 2 things. 1) Could you clarify the part about how many of these repetitive values will be needed? Is it 8 (like in the example) or can be any number? If yes, how is that determined? 2) What have you already tried in terms of the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(8)).assign(hour=np.tile(np.arange(1,9),2))
```

Output:

```
         Date  ID number  hour
0  15/06/2022       1523     1
0  15/06/2022       1523     2
0  15/06/2022       1523     3
0  15/06/2022       1523     4
0  15/06/2022       1523     5
0  15/06/2022       1523     6
0  15/06/2022       1523     7
0  15/06/2022       1523     8
1  15/06/2022       1402     1
1  15/06/2022       1402     2
1  15/06/2022       1402     3
1  15/06/2022       1402     4
1  15/06/2022       1402     5
1  15/06/2022       1402     6
1  15/06/2022       1402     7
1  15/06/2022       1402     8
```

And, you can add `.reset_index()` to get unique indexing for the rows also.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply and concat the df

`pd.concat([df]*8).sort_values('ID number')`

```
         Date  ID number
1  15/06/2022       1402
1  15/06/2022       1402
1  15/06/2022       1402
1  15/06/2022       1402
1  15/06/2022       1402
1  15/06/2022       1402
1  15/06/2022       1402
1  15/06/2022       1402
0  15/06/2022       1523
0  15/06/2022       1523
0  15/06/2022       1523
0  15/06/2022       1523
0  15/06/2022       1523
0  15/06/2022       1523
0  15/06/2022       1523
0  15/06/2022       1523
```

Comment: `df.reindex(df.index.repeat(8))`